Is it possible to provide an npm build command during a git push to heroku?
The relevant part of my package.json looks like this:
"scripts": {
    "build-1": "cd proj1/client && npm i && npm run build && cd ../..",
    "build-2": "cd proj2/client && npm i && npm run build && cd ../..",
    "build-3": "cd proj3 && npm i && npm run build && cd ..",
    "build-4": "cd proj4 && npm i && npm run build && cd ..",
    "build": "npm run build-1 && npm run build-2 && npm run build-3 && npm run build-4"
}

But now if I want to push an update to proj3, it will trigger a re-build for every project. Ideally I want to do something like git push heroku main --build build-3.
Is this or something like it supported/possible?
